# datetime utcoffset, total_seconds()

Tags: python, datetime, utc

**Вопрос 1.**
Почему в приведенном ниже коде для текущего времени с учетом часовых поясов (типа datetime) значение utc offset для разных часовых поясов получается целое (2,3 часа), а для значения datetime созданного для конкретных значений часов, минут, секунда какие-то странные значения: для Каира 02:05, для Киева +02:02, для Лондона -00:01

```
from datetime import *
import pytz
    d = []
d.append({'tz':pytz.timezone('Africa/Cairo')})
d.append({'tz':pytz.timezone('Europe/Kiev')})
d.append({'tz':pytz.timezone('Europe/London')})

for i in range(len(d)):
    # d[i].update({'now':now[i]})
    d[i].update({'now': datetime.now(d[i].get('tz'))})
    d[i].update({'reminder_datetime': datetime(year=1, month=1, 
    day=1, hour=12, minute=0, tzinfo=d[i]['tz'])})
    d[i].update({'reminder_time': time(hour=12, minute=0, 
    tzinfo=d[i]['tz'])})


for i in range(len(d)):
    tz = d[i]['tz']
    cur = d[i]['now']
    reminder = d[i]['reminder_datetime']
    reminder_time = d[i]['reminder_time']
    offset = reminder.utcoffset().total_seconds()
    offset_time = reminder_time.utcoffset().total_seconds()
```

**Вывод:**

Время текущее в Africa/Cairo: 2022-04-12 14:16:41.890879+02:00
Напоминание на 12:00:00 по
**Africa/Cairo: 0001-01-01 12:00:00+02:05**
Время текущее в Europe/Kiev: 2022-04-12 15:16:41.890879+03:00
Напоминание на 12:00:00 по
**Europe/Kiev: 0001-01-01 12:00:00+02:02**
Время текущее в Europe/London: 2022-04-12 13:16:41.890879+01:00
Напоминание на 12:00:00 по
**Europe/London: 0001-01-01 12:00:00-00:01**

**Вопрос 2.**
Почему для типа time функция получения utcoffset возвращает None, а для datetime корректно возвращает количество секунд смещения времени?

Comment: Потому что вы зачем-то указываете год, в котором Иисус Христос был ещё младенцем — очевидно, две тысячи лет назад часовые пояса отличались от текущих (а точнее, часовых поясов не было вообще и все жили по [местному солнечному времени](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F) — видимо, именно его и показывает pytz)

Comment: Ну а тип time в принципе не может иметь часовой пояс, потому что для вычисления часового пояса нужно знать точную дату

Comment: После установки года в значение 2022 ничего не изменилось - функция по прежнему возвращает None.

datetime(year=2022, month=1, day=1, hour=12, minute=0, tzinfo=d[i]['tz'])